# What is the most efficient way to check whether a template exist within the contents of a Mediawiki article?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I looked into the "text" table in the SQL database and found the fields for the page contents rather complicated. Was trying to use WhatLinksHere but got myself into a bigger mess.

I believe there must be a simple method that I can use, judging from the ReplaceText extension, as well as the Search php files. But those files do really look cryptic to me, since they referenced some other files. I wonder if anyone can help me out on this.

(P/S: I looked into the "pagelinks" table and saw only pl_from. Wonder why there is no pl_to?)

Answer (score 0):

Template transclusions are recorded in the [`templatelinks` table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTemplatelinks_table), not in [`pagelinks`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPagelinks_table).

The format of both tables is the same: the `tl_from` field contains the page ID of the linking / transcluding page, while the fields `tl_namespace` and `tl_title` contain the namespace and normalized (DB key form, i.e. underscores for spaces) title of the target page being transcluded.

For templatelinks, the target [namespace](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aNamespace#Built-in_namespaces) will *usually* be 10 (Template), but this need not always be the case: pages in any namespace can be transcluded using the syntax `{{Namespace:Title}}` (or just `{{:Title}}` for pages in the main namespace).

The reason for this asymmetry is that, while the *transcluding* page must, necessarily, exist, there's no guarantee that the template being transcluded does.  Thus, the target page might not *have* a page ID, and so we need to refer to it using its title (and namespace).